# ¿Multiples llaves foraneas dentro de un campo de otro tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, android-studio, base-de-datos

Buen Día, estoy desarrollando una aplicación de Android en donde tengo esta base de datos.

-Tabla Comida:

- ID Primary Key char (15)
- Nombre char (25)
- Descripcion char (35)
- Etiquetas char (35)

-Tabla Etiquetas:

- ID Primary Key char (15)
- Nombre char (15)

Una explicacion de todo, en mi base de datos la llave primaria de la tabla etiquetas se va conectar mediante una llave foranea al campo de etiquetas en la tabla comidas. **¿Es posible que pueda llevar multiples llaves foraneas dentro de este campo?, Y de ser asi como lo hago?** Debido a que quiero que la app tenga varias etiquetas para que se puedan buscar las comidas mediante estas, si no **¿Hay manera de optimizar la base de datos?**.

Answer (score -2):

No. primero, las claves deberian ser numericas. Despues, si fueran varchar, deberian ser exactamente iguales.

Y para lo que vos queres, te recomiendo que leas sobre teoria de base de datos, pero necesitas una tabla intermedia, ya que tenes una relacion NXM, que quiere decir que vas a tener muchos registros en una tabla relacionados a muchos registros en otra tabla.

Por lo tanto, deberias tener 1 tabla intermedia asi:

```
Tabla EtiquetasComida:
IdEtiquetaComida
IdEtiqueta
IdComida
```